# How to align a scroll bar with text?

Tags: html, css

In below fiddle the scroll bar is at top of fiddle. I need the scroll bar to be at same level as first element of text but also move the scroll bar vertically down 40 pixels.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebLSe/7/

Is there a css option to align the scroll bar with the itself ?

Fiddle code :

```
    <div class="scroll">
    <table  >
      <tr><td>
        test
        </tr></td>
        <tr><td>
        test
        </tr></td>
        <tr><td>
        test
        </tr></td>
        <tr><td>
        test
        </tr></td>
      </table>
    </div>

   .scroll {
    height: 80px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.modeDown {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Remove the top padding of the div?

Comment: @Baszz ive updated question & fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is further down the div as you have given the `.scroll` top padding of `40px`. If you change this value, your text will move further up the div.  You may also need to change the height as at the moment your div has a height of 80px (40px height plus 40px padding).

To keep the div further down the page then you need to add either `margin-top:40px` to `.scroll` or you can put it in an extra div with a padding top of 40px

```
.scroll {
    margin-top:40px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: ive updated the question & fiddle, I also need to move the scroll bar vertically down 40 pixels

Comment: add margin-top:40px; to .scroll it should move the scroll div down 40px, if that doesn't work you can put it in another div and give 40px top padding to that